# Are ActiveAndroid .save() operations executed on the main thread or asynchronously?

Tags: android, activeandroid

Im using the ActiveAndroid library and I have read the entire information (very minimalist and insufficient unfortunately)
There is no mention whether the `.save()` operation is executed syncrhonously.

If it is asynchronous, how do I "listen" for it to end before proceeding?

http://www.activeandroid.com/ - this is the documentation I read

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a look at the source code of the [Model](https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid/blob/master/src/com/activeandroid/Model.java) class, you'll see that the [`save`](https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid/blob/master/src/com/activeandroid/Model.java#L74) method does not do any thread handling:

```
public final Long save() {
    final SQLiteDatabase db = Cache.openDatabase();
    final ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    for (Field field : mTableInfo.getFields()) {
        /* ... */
    }

    if (mId == null) {
        mId = db.insert(mTableInfo.getTableName(), null, values);
    }
    else {
        db.update(mTableInfo.getTableName(), values, idName+"=" + mId, null);
    }

    Cache.getContext().getContentResolver()
            .notifyChange(ContentProvider.createUri(mTableInfo.getType(), mId), null);
    return mId;
}
```

Saving thus occurs synchronously.

Comment: I looked at that but I considered the possibility that maybe the deferring to another thread might happen somewhere else at a higher level

Comment: What should we do when we want to use `.save()` and `Update()` in a separate thread other than of main thread. Because it shows ANR on `.save()` and `Update()` for many records.